# What value should the $bundle_name parameter for fileld_info_instances() get?

Tags: nodes

In a module, I need to get the list of fields for a content type. I used the following code, but `$instances` does not contain any helpful value.

```php
$instances = field_info_instances('node', 'indicatorsheet_page');
```

Which value should I use for `$content_type`? Isn't it the content type machine name?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here seems correct to me, bear in mind that you can leave the bundle parameter empty and then you'll get an array of results keyed by bundle so you can evaluate if there's a problem with the machine name of the bundle you're using:

```
  $instances = field_info_instances('node');
```

You can also access admin/reports/fields and take a look to fields and content types available in your site.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument required from `field_info_instances()` is the machine name for a content type. If the function doesn't return any information when `'node'` and `'indicatorsheet_page'` are passed as arguments, that could mean:

- The content type name isn't correct
- The content type name is correct, but that isn't a node content type
- The content type name is correct, and that is a node content type, but it doesn't have any field that isn't marked as deleted

Since the field information is cached, it could also be the *cache_field* cache has been corrupted.

For debugging purposes, you can check what `field_read_fields(array('entity_type' => 'node'), array('include_deleted' => TRUE, 'include_inactive'))` and `field_read_instances(array('entity_type' => 'node'), array('include_deleted' => TRUE, 'include_inactive'))`. Both the function calls return information for fields of every node content type, including information for those fields have been marked as deleted or inactive fields.